# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 21) vs (21, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to reproduce [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389018/big-loss-and-low-accuracy-on-training-data-in-both-bert-and-albert) example using huggingface `TFBertModel` to do a classification task.

My model is almost the same of the example, but I'm performing multilabel classification. For this reason, I've performed the binarization of my labels using sklearn's `MultiLabelBinarizer`.

Then, I've adapted my model to have the predictions accordingly.

```
def loadBertModel(max_length,n_classes):

  bert_model = TFBertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-multilingual-uncased')

  input_ids = keras.Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=np.int32)
  attention_mask = keras.Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=np.int32)
  token_type_ids = keras.Input(shape=(max_length,), dtype=np.int32)

  _, output = bert_model([input_ids, attention_mask,token_type_ids])
  
  output = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="sigmoid", name="dense_out_dom")(output)

  model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask,token_type_ids],
    outputs=output,
    name='bert_classifier',
  )       

  model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(lr=2e-5),  
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  )

  model.summary()
  return model
```

Also, I'm using tensorflow's `Dataset` to produce my model's inputs:

```
def map_example_to_dict(input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids, label): 
  return {
      "input_ids": input_ids,
      "token_type_ids": token_type_ids,
      "attention_mask": attention_masks,
  }, label
  

def tokenize_sequences(tokenizer, max_length, corpus, labels):
  input_ids = []
  token_type_ids = []
  attention_masks = []

  for i in tqdm(range(len(corpus))):
    encoded = tokenizer.encode_plus(
        corpus[i], 
        max_length=max_length, 
        add_special_tokens=True,
        padding='max_length',
        truncation=True,
        return_token_type_ids=True,
        return_attention_mask=True,  # add attention mask to not focus on pad tokens)
        return_tensors="tf"
    )
    input_ids.append(encoded["input_ids"])
    attention_masks.append(encoded["attention_mask"])
    token_type_ids.append(encoded["token_type_ids"])

  input_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_ids)
  attention_masks = tf.convert_to_tensor(attention_masks)
  token_type_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(token_type_ids)
  
  labels = labels.toarray()

  return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_ids, attention_masks, token_type_ids, labels)).map(map_example_to_dict)
```

Finally, when I try to fit my model, I have an incoherence concerning the logits and the labels' shapes:

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 21) vs (21, 1))
```

I really don't know if the `Dataset` transformation is messing with my inputs' shapes or if I'm missing some other detail. Any ideas?

Full stack trace:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-42-19f4c0665eeb> in <module>()
      4       epochs=N_EPOCHS,
      5       verbose=1,
----> 6       batch_size=1,
      7       )

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1605 binary_crossentropy
        K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits), axis=-1)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4814 binary_crossentropy
        return nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py:174 sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
        (logits.get_shape(), labels.get_shape()))

    ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((1, 21) vs (21, 1))
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa it is a bit long, but I edited my post with the stack trace.

Comment: Seems like your labels have a shape of `(21,1)`, indicating 21 data points. Instetad you have 1 data point with 21 possible labels. Hence, it should be `(1,21) `. This can simply be done by `labels=lables.view(1,-1)` after `labels = labels.toarray()`

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, thanks for your suggestion. With your insights, I managed to fix my bug. What I had to do was adding a new line `labels = np.array([i.reshape(1,-1) for i in labels ])` after `labels = labels.toarray()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like for a single example your labels have a shape of `(21,1)`, indicating 21 data points. Instead you have 1 data point with 21 possible labels. Hence, it should be `(1,21)` . You have to reshape the data accordingly.